# Swift / XCode compiling Archive takes 25 minuts for a very small App

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, compilation

I have a very small (one pager) Swift App. The only feature ist to show Values of an Array - a little calculating and so on. My Main ViewController has 1600 rows of Code. 1100 rows of these 1600 are just defining an huge Array. So...very small...

When XCode compiles an Archive it takes 25 minutes and "stuck" on my Main ViewController File. Development / Test compiling for my iOS Device takes just 15 seconds or something...

When i now reduce the big Array to 200 Items the Archive compiling process takes only less than 1 minute. But why the heck does it take more than 25 times more time for an simple static Array that is only 5 - 6 times bigger?

The Array is defined like this:

```
var myBigArray: NSArray = [
    ["Value 1","Attribute 1","Attribute 2","Attribute 3"],
    ["Value 2","Attribute 1","Attribute 2","Attribute 3"],
    ["Value 3","Attribute 1","Attribute 2","Attribute 3"],
    ["Value 4","Attribute 1","Attribute 2","Attribute 3"],
    ["Value 5","Attribute 1","Attribute 2","Attribute 3"],
    ....
]
```

Comment: Still as of today Swift 2.3 is slow as a turtle! Half hour each archiving ... how disgusting is the Xcode/Swift environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array is that huge, you should not hardcode it. Better use another approach like reading a CSV/JSON file or CoreData. However, the latter might be already overkill.

Another approach would be: if the array is that predictable like you are showing it, then generate it online (i.e. at run-time) and not offline.

Answer (score 0):

Compilation performance is one of the early issues of Swift. It is supposed to be quicker in the latest Xcode beta (6.3 beta 2 as of now).
Try that and if it is better then you only have to wait until 6.3 is the current stable version.

Comment: Reading this comment whilst waiting for my Xcode 8.2 with Swift 3.0 code to compile makes me sad